# Import cannot be resolved Pylance(report missingImports) Error

Tags: python

[Cannot import from pyc file in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqGgY.png)

Can anybody help me out how to fix this error please. Image is attached below

Comment: While you can import a `.pyc` file, an IDE can not analyze it.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or errors. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to import a `.pyc` file into a `.py` file. A `.pyc` file includes compiled python code so I think you would have to first convert it into python code if you want to import it. This [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/) might be helpful. (Download it and try to convert the `.pyc` file.)

Comment: I tried it via this software but it failed . Moreover, i have seen other students successfully importing "test robot movement" from this pyc file